# Redshift: InvalidParameter Value Invalid marker: Please use the marker returned from the prior request or omit the marker parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am getting the following error on my Redshift cluster every time I click on the **Maintenance and Monitoring** tab.

```
InvalidParameterValue Invalid marker: Please use the marker returned from the prior request or omit the marker parameter.
```

My parameters group for the cluster has been set to default as shown in the dock below. I have rebooted the cluster but the same error message appears.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-parameter-groups.html

[image: parameter group]

What changes should I make to stop the invalid parameter error.

Answer (score 0):

That is an error thrown by the AWS API and based on your description is happening when the console page loads.  I wouldn’t conclude that this must have something to do with your parameter group settings but it could.  When you click on that tab you web browser running the console has to collect information from AWS using API calls.  Since you are just loading information and the call is failing it is possible that the issue is just with how the API call is made and not with the Redshift cluster itself.

I’d start by flushing browser cache and history or using another browser as a test. There’s a good chance this is just bad info stuck in your browser cache.

If that doesn’t work I’d ask around to see if others are having the same issues and if so I’d try and pull the same info by using the AWS CLI to make the API calls.  If the API calls are really not working at the server you will need to submit a support ticket but it is highly likely the issue is on the calling side.